# unable to add/show subview to display after tableview is empty

Tags: ios, uitableview, delete-row

I have a tableview that displays an array of products. whenever an empty tableview loads i display a label asking the user to search for products.

I want that same subview to be displayed when the user deletes all products from this view. I'm firing off the method but the view will NOT display after the user deletes the last product.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        MSAProduct* product = _history[indexPath.row];
        [_history removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [_db deleteFromHistory:product.model];
        _history = [_db getHistory];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self checkForEmptyHistory];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}


-(void)checkForEmptyHistory{
if (_history.count == 0) {
    emptyHistoryView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MSAEmptyHistoryViewController"];
    [self.myPageSubView addSubview:emptyHistoryView.view];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myPageSubView];
    NSLog(@"Sub View should be visible");
}
else if (_history.count >0)
{
    [self.tableView setHidden:NO];
    [myPageSubView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

}

Comment: Did you check the emptyHistoryView.view's frame?

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(emptyHistoryView.view.frame));

Comment: i got this back {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}

Comment: thanks I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding and removing the subview. I simply add the subview and toggle the hidden property of the subview.